# Issue with theme mod options during domain migration

Tags: themes, migration, theme-options, get-theme-mod

I want to migrate my development wordpress site to the production domain. In order to success the migration I found and replace all previous url occurences (http://localhost) to the new (https://mywebsite.com).
The problem is that old urls cannot be replaced directly in the field `option_value` of `theme_mods_{your theme name}` in the table `wp_options` because data in there are serialized.

How can I replace old urls by the new without breaking theme settings ?

Comment: You shouldn't store URLs, store attachment post IDs instead then use the API functions to get the URL back. Then you won't need to change them when you migrate the site. Have you looked at the WP CLI search replace command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to search and replace old urls to new ones by using `maybe_unserialize(get_theme_mods())` and `get_theme_mod()` WP functions and following these steps:

1. Create a php file in the root folder of your WP installation (same path as `wp-load.php`).
2. Insert the following code :

```php
require_once("wp-load.php");
$r = maybe_unserialize(get_theme_mods());
foreach ($r as $k => $v){
    if(!empty($k)){
        $ListOptions[] = $k;
    }
}
foreach($ListOptions as $option){
    $str = get_theme_mod($option);
    $str = str_replace('http://localhost', 'https://mywebsite.com', $str);
    $str = str_replace('http:\\/\\/localhost', 'https:\\/\\/mediadroit.fr', $str);
    set_theme_mod($option, $str);
    var_dump('|'.$option.': '.get_theme_mod($option).' ===> '.$str);
    echo "\n";
}
```

3. Execute the script

Comment: I indented your code, but this would be better off as a WP CLI command

Answer (score 1):

Use the official CLI tool:

```
wp search-replace 'http://localhost' 'https://yoursitecom'
```

It will automatically deserialize any post meta, options, theme mods, etc and adjust them to match the new URL.

Fundamentally though, it's bad practice to store URLs to images posts and assets in the database. Store the post ID instead, and this problem goes away

Comment: I agree with you for the bad practice ouf using url but the my theme’s cutomizer (hestia) uses absolute urls.